# Can I register a domain name with a suffix from another country?

Tags: domain-registration

I saw a lot of .be from belgium, for example.  Can I just make up a domain and with the .be and use it?

Answer (score 5):

It depends. Some countries have restrictions on who can register them, ie. you have to be a resident or you have to be a business in that country.

For [.be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.be) there are no restrictions.

For a full list of domains and any restrictions have a look at [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Country_code_top-level_domains).